# String won't be written to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code which I am writing 'testing' into, once the file is done I was hoping to see 'testing' in the text file but it is still empty. Am I missing something here?

```
import shutil
import sys
f = open('test.txt', 'r+')
f.write('testing')
shutil.copyfileobj(f, sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to close the file.

`f.close()`

EDIT

try changing the name of the file, Is it still not writting:

```
f = open('test124.txt', 'a') # use the append flag so that it creates the file. 
f.write('testing')
f.close()
```

Comment: No, that shouldn't and doesn't change anything

Comment: @AshleyMcManamon Of course it should. Only after closing the file, the data are guaranteed to be readable out of the file again. Of course, you have to close the file before copying.

Comment: @AshleyMcManamon Unless you use with open, you really should close the file just to be safe.

Comment: I restarted my computer and it is fixed something must have bugged up the python compiler thanks for the help though!

Comment: Still think you should add the `f.close()` or use `with open`

Comment: Closing the file doesn't work in this case because shutil.copyfileobj() needs an open file to work with. closing or flushing the file is needed if some external entity wants to use it, but not here. Seeking to the beginning of the file as suggested elsewhere should work.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually correct, the problem is that when you `write`, the buffer pointer moves, so when you copy, it won't print anything. Try with `seek` before like this:

```
import shutil
import sys
f = open('test.txt', 'r+')
f.write('testing')
f.seek(0)
shutil.copyfileobj(f, sys.stdout)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn;t this true ?  'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing.
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: No r+ makes it readable and writable, from documentation " 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing".

Comment: Actually, `shutil` does something really weird after writing with `f.write`

Comment: I think I got it, the code is correct, the problem is the buffer's position.